# input type=range not styling in ie11

Tags: html, css

The input tag renders properly in every browser except
ie11.  In ie, it occupies vertical space which I am unable to override with,
for example,

```
<input type='range' style='height: 20px' />
```

None of the canned css cross browser generators are successful in getting
rid of the default vertical space that the input tag takes up in ie11.  My
project requires many stacked sliders, and I would like a solution that is
cross browser independent.  Can you help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In ie11, the input type=range tag is displayed with default
padding.  Remove the padding when the tag is styled, for example,

```
<input type="range" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; height: 20px" />
```

Be sure that the track and thumb 'fit' in the desired height.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent hours looking for this answer, couldn't figure out why setting a height made the range slider disappear